# Substitute for Codonics Clarity Viewer?

Tags: image-viewers

I got a CD which data requires Codonics Clarity Viewer which is licenced [program](http://www.codonics.com/Products/Viewers/). 
I recall in viewing such data with some free OSX application last year.
I did not find the software or its substitute by `apt-cache/apt-file search`.

Is there any substitute for Codonics Clarity Viewer in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also [Weasis](https://dcm4che.atlassian.net/wiki/display/WEA/Installing+Weasis+in+DCM4CHEE) which is a system that can launch an image viewer. 
It follows some DICOM standards.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it's a DICOM file format file, in Ubuntu, you have at least two alternatives:

- **DicomImageViewer**: To install, run `sudo apt-get install pixelmed-webstart-apps`
- **Aeskulap**: To install, run `sudo apt-get install aeskulap`

Also you can search the application names in the Ubuntu Software Center. Is slower but easier.

Comment: Why downvoters? There are DICOM medical packages in apt-cache search.

Comment: @Masi. The answer has been [edited](http://askubuntu.com/posts/682710/revisions). I have now removed my downvote.